# Rails: many to many relationship join table design

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

Model Material & Manager is many to many relationship,
this means Material needs to be checked by many managers,managers check many materials.
ManageMaterial is join table with attributes

```
material_id
manager_id
```

I load some data into join table like this

```
id          manager_id     material_id                  
----------  ----------  ----------- 
1           6           52           
2           8           52
3           2           12
4           5           12
```

Now I want to show what materials are being checked, in this example I just want one item with material_id = 52, but if I do @items = ManageMaterial.all , it will return two items.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: `@items = ManageMaterial.find_by_material_id(52)` it'll return a single document with material id 52

Comment: @Emu Thanks, if more than one material_id, How to loop through each material_id?

Comment: Didn't get your question. Can you elaborate? Or you can give me an example.

Comment: like edited example below, how to get two items with only material_id = 12 & 52 without duplication

Comment: try ```ManageMaterial.where(material_id: 52)```, it returns all records where  material_id = 52

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get `ManageMaterial`s without duplication:

```
@items = ManageMaterial.select("DISTINCT(material_id)")
```

If you want a single `ManageMaterial` with `material_id`:

```
@items = ManageMaterial.find_by_material_id(52)
```